# Taskbar icon with multi frame app in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, imageicon, taskbar

I have a Java Swing application where several frames could be opened at once. Each of the frames has its own icon image. How does it determined by OS which of the icons should be used in the task bar.
And is there any way to switch the icon to another frame' icon?

Comment: ```JFrames``` are always displayed in the task bar. Instead of using ```JFrames``` you could use ```JDialogs```, which show up as ```JFrames``` but don't appear on the task bar. Just use the ```JFrame``` object for the icon you want to see displayed.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the existing system. There are JFrames and I need to find solution for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given JFrame 1, JFrame 2 and JFrame 3 each one with its respective icon:

**The setIcons method:**

```
public void setIcons(List<JFrame> frames, Image icon) {
    List<Image> iconAsList = new ArrayList<Image>();
    iconAsList.add(icon);
    for(JFrame frame: frames) {
        frame.setIconImages(iconAsList);
    }
}
```

**Other code:**

```
...
List<JFrame> frames = new ArrayList<JFrame>();
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
Image icon1 = new ImageIcon("icon1.png").getImage();
Image icon2 = new ImageIcon("icon2.png").getImage();
Image icon3 = new ImageIcon("icon3.png").getImage();

frames.add(frame1);
frames.add(frame2);
frames.add(frame3);

setIcons(frames, icon1); //Set all frames to use icon 1

//DO OTHER STUFF

setIcons(frames, icon3); //Set all frames to use icon 3
...
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I tried it but all frames got the same icon. And every frame must have its own icon.
But thanks to you answer helped me to find the solution! As it's known frame.getIconImages() returns a list of icons with different dimensions. And I only change for every frame the biggest icon. I noticed that in Windows OS the biggest one is used as taskbar icon and smaller one as icon on window header title.
So changing the biggest affects thr taskbar icon and the title icon is not changed.